# I don't understand why my Node.js code is not executing concurrently

Tags: node.js

I don't understand why the results display 'cat' first, followed by 'dog', and then 'bird'. I expect to see 'bird' first, followed by 'dog', and finally 'cat'.

```
async function asyncOperation1() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        let x = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {

            x += 1;
        }

        console.log(`cat`, x);

        resolve(x)
    });
}

async function asyncOperation2() {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        let x = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            x += 1;
        }

        console.log(`dog`, x);

        resolve(x)
    });
}

async function concurrentExecution() {

    try {

        asyncOperation1();
        asyncOperation2();

        console.log("bird");

    } catch (error) {

        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    }
}

concurrentExecution();
```

I am using Node.js version 18.19.0. I attempted to run the code, but the result did not meet my expectations, as I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score -4):

add await in front of asyncOperation1 and asyncOperation2 i.e
`await asyncOperation1(); await asyncOperation2();`

Comment: Even after adding await asyncOperation1(); await asyncOperation2(); the code still displays 'cat' first, followed by 'dog', and finally 'bird'. I don't understand why.